# How are Ethereum bytecode JUMPs and JUMPDESTs resolved?

Tags: bytecode, ethereum, smartcontracts, evm

I've been looking around for info on how Ethereum deals with jumps and jump destinations. From various blogs and the yellow paper what I found is as follows:

The operand taken by `JUMP` and the first of the two operands taken by `JUMPI` are the value the the `PC` is set to (assume the first stack value != 0 in the case of `JUMPI`).

However, looking at [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xab7c74abc0c4d48d1bdad5dcb26153fc8780f83e#code) contract's creation code (as opcodes) the first few opcodes/values are:

`PUSH1 0x60
PUSH1 0x40
MSTORE
CALLDATASIZE
ISZERO
PUSH2 0x00f8
JUMPI`

As I understand it this means that if the value pushed to the stack by `ISZERO` != 0 then `PC` will change to `0x00f8` as `JUMPI` takes two from the stack, checks if the second is 0 and if not sets `PC` to the value of its first operand.

The problem I am having is that `0x00f8` in decimal is `248`. The 248th position in the contract appears to be `MSTORE` and not a `JUMPDEST`, which would cause the contract to fail in its execution as `JUMP*` can only point to a valid `JUMPDEST`.

Presumably contracts don't jump to invalid destinations on purpose?

If anyone could explain how jumps and jump destinations are resolved I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps others:

The confusion arose from the EVM reading byte by byte and NOT word by word.

From the example in the question, `0x00f8` would  be the 248th byte, not the 248th word.

As each opcode is 1 byte long `PC` is normally incremented by 1 when reading an opcode.

However in the case of a `PUSH` instruction, information on how many of the following bytes are to be taken as its operand is also included.

For example `PUSH2` takes the 2 bytes that follow it, `PUSH6` takes 6 bytes that follow it, and so on. Here `PC` would be incremented by 1 for the `PUSH` and then 2 or 6 respectively for each byte of the data used by the `PUSH`.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that there is a difference in **JUMP** and **JUMPI**.

**JUMP** just takes 1 element from the stack i.e. destination. Which is generally an offset in hex pushed to the stack.

**JUMPI** is a conditional jump that takes top 2 elements from the stack i.e. destination and condition.

In the example you gave the condition is **ISZERO**(checks if the top most element of the stack is 0 or not).
So if that returns true, it will JUMP to the desitnation that is the offset 0x00f8(248 in decimal).

If the condition is False, it will just increase the program counter by 1.

In the contract you mentioned, it is a JUMPDEST opcode at (Program counter)248.

The program counter depends on the opcode. How much many bytes does a opcode push into the stack,etc. e.g.

```
PUSH1 0x60  - PC[0]
PUSH1 0x40  - PC[2]
MSTORE      - PC[4]
CALLDATASIZE- PC[5]
ISZERO      - PC[6]
PUSH2 0x00f8- PC[7]
JUMPI       - PC[10]
```

Maybe this website will give you a better understanding on opcodes https://ethervm.io/